# Computing the De Rham Cohomology Group of Connected Sum $H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1 \# M_2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I'm reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. I have a question about **problem 17-7**.

> **Problem 17-7** Let $M_1$, $M_2$ be connected smooth manifolds of dimension $n\geq3$, and let $M_1\# M_2$ denote their smooth connected
> sum (Example 9.31). Prove that $H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1 \# M_2)\cong H_{\rm
> dR}^p(M_1)\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(M_2)$ for $0<p<n-1$. Prove that the same
> is true for $p=n-1$ if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are both compact and
> orientable. [Hint: use Problems 9-12 and 17-6.]
>
> **Problem 9-12** Suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected smooth $n$-manifolds and $M_1\# M_2$ is their smooth connected sum (see
> Example 9.31). Show that the smooth structure on $M_1\# M_2$ can be
> chosen in such a way that there are open subsets $\widetilde{M_1},
> \widetilde{M_2}\subseteq M_1\# M_2$ that are diffeomorphic to
> $M_1-\{p_1\}$ and $M_2-\{p_2\}$, respectively, such that
> $\widetilde{M_1}\cup\widetilde{M_2}=M_1\# M_2$ and
> $\widetilde{M_1}\cap\widetilde{M_2}$ is diffeomorphic to
> $(-1,1)\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.
>
> **Problem 17-6** Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold of dimension $n\geq3$. For any $x\in M$ and $0\leq p\leq n-2$, prove that the map
> $H_{\rm dR}^p(M)\rightarrow H_{\rm dR}^p(M-\{x\})$ induced by
> inclusion $M-\{x\}\hookrightarrow M$ is an isomorphism. Prove that the
> same is true for $p=n-1$ if $M$ is compact and orientable.

**Here is my attempt about problem 17-7:**

According to problem 9-12, there are open subsets $\widetilde{M_1}, \widetilde{M_2}\subseteq M_1\# M_2$, such that $\widetilde{M_1}$ is diffeomorphic to $M_1-\{p_1\}$, $\widetilde{M_2}$ is diffeomorphic to $M_2-\{p_2\}$, $\widetilde{M_1}\cup\widetilde{M_2}=M_1\# M_2$ and $\widetilde{M_1}\cap\widetilde{M_2}$ is diffeomorphic to $(-1,1)\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Note that $(-1,1)\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and $\{0\}\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ are homotopy equivalent, and $\{0\}\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Therefore $H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_1}\cap\widetilde{M_2})\cong H_{\rm dR}^p((-1,1)\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})=0$ for $0<p<n-1$.

According to Mayer–Vietoris Theorem,
$$\cdots\rightarrow H_{\rm dR}^{p-1}(\widetilde{M_1}\cap\widetilde{M_2})\rightarrow H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1\# M_2)\rightarrow H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_1})\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_2})\rightarrow H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_1}\cap\widetilde{M_2})\rightarrow\cdots$$
is exact. The groups on both ends are trivial when $1<p<n-1$, which implies that
$$H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1 \# M_2)\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_1})\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_2})\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1-\{p_1\})\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(M_2-\{p_2\}).$$
According to problem 17-6, for $0\leq p\leq n-2$,
$$H_{\rm dR}^p(M_i-\{p_i\})\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(M_i),i=1,2.$$
Therefore
$$H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1 \# M_2)\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1)\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(M_2)$$
for $1<p<n-1$.

**My question is how to handle the cases $p=1$ and $p=n-1$.** Group on the left end of the exact sequence is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (not trivial) when $p=1$. If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are both compact and orientable, according to problem 17-6, though
$$H_{\rm dR}^{n-1}(M_i-\{p_i\})\cong H_{\rm dR}^{n-1}(M_i),i=1,2,$$
group on the right end of the exact sequence is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (not trivial). Both of the two cases will make it unclear to directly infer
$$H_{\rm dR}^p(M_1 \# M_2)\cong H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_1})\oplus H_{\rm dR}^p(\widetilde{M_2}).$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you already know how to solve Problems 9-12 and 17-6?

Comment: @Jason DeVito No, our professor has no requirements for problem 9-12 and 17-6 for the time being...

Comment: I see.  Do you know Stokes's theorem?  If not, what theorems do you know about closed orientable manifolds?

Comment: @Jason DeVito I know Stokes's theorem. Moreover, if $M$ is a compact connected orientable smooth $n$-manifold, then $H_{\rm dR}^n(M)$ is 1-dimensional, and is spanned by the cohomology class of any smooth orientation form. If M is a noncompact connected orientable smooth $n$-manifold, then $H_{\rm dR}^n(M)=0$.

Comment: Got it!  I can finish an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the other answer, I'll write $U$ for $\widetilde{M_1}$ and $V$ for $\widetilde{M_2}$ just to save on typing.

The $p=1$ case is doesn't depend on orientability or having closed manifolds.

The Mayer-Vietoris sequence starts with $$0\rightarrow H_{dR}^0(M)\rightarrow H_{dR}^0(U)\oplus H_{dR}^0(V)\rightarrow  H_{dR}^0(U\cap V)\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(U)\oplus H^1_{dR}(V)\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(U\cap V).$$

But $H^0_{dR}$ measures the number of components.  Indeed, there are no $(-1)$-forms, so $H^0_{dR}$ is simply the kernel of the differential $d$, when restricted to functions.    But a function with trivial derivative is constant on connected sets.  Because $n\geq 2$, both $U$ and $V$ are connected.  In addition, as you noted, $U\cap V$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ and $n\geq 3$, so $H^1_{dR}(U\cap V) = 0$.

Thus, the MV sequence looks like $$0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow  H^1_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(U)\oplus H^1_{dR}(V)\rightarrow 0.$$

The first map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is injective, so the image is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This must be the kernel of the map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Now the rank-nullity theorem implies that this map has rank $1$, so it must actually be surjective.  That is, the map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has image all of $\mathbb{R}$.  This is the kernel of the map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(M)$.  In other words, the map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(M)$ is the $0$ map.  Exactness now implies that the map $H^1_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^1_{dR}(U)\oplus H^1_{dR}(V)$ is injective.  Since it is also surjective, it must be an isomorphism.  This concludes the $p=1$ case.

For the $p=n-1$ case, we'll have to work a bit harder.  As you noted, using the fact that $H_{dR}^\ast(S^{n-1})$ is known, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence looks like

$$0\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U)\oplus H^{n-1}_{dR}(V)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^n_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^n_{dR}(U)\oplus H^n_{dR}(V)\rightarrow 0$$

**Claim**:  The map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(U)\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U\cap V)$ is the $0$-map.  So is the map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(V)\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U\cap V)$.

Let's believe the Claim for now.  Believing it, the map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(U)\oplus H^{n-1}_{dR}(V)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ must be the zero map.  Thus, its kernel is everything.  Exactness now implies the map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(M)\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U)\oplus H^{n-1}_{dR}(V)$ is surjective.  Since this map is also injective, it is an isomorphism when $p=n-1$ as well.

Thus, we need only prove the Claim:

Proof: I'll just prove this for $U$, the proof for $V$ being analogous.

As you noted, $U\cap V$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times (-1,1)$, and I'm thinking of $S^{n-1}\times \{1-\epsilon\}$ as being a very tiny ball around the deleted point in $M_1$.  Consider the homotopy where we retract the interval $(-1,1)$ to $(-1,0]$.  Performing this homotopy on $U$ (keeping points of $U\setminus (S^{n-1}\times (0,1)$) fixed, we see that the pair $(U,U\cap V)$ is homotopy equivalent to $(M'_1, \partial M_1')$ where $M_1'$ denotes $M_1$ with a small ball removed and $\partial M_1'\cong S^{n-1}$.

So, instead of studying the map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(U)\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U\cap V)$, we may instead study the map $H^{n-1}_{dR}(M_1')\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(\partial M_1')$.  Because $M_1$ is closed and orientable, $M_1'$, is a compact orientable manifold with boundary, so is amenable to Stokes's theorem.

Now, let $[\eta]\in H^{n-1}_{dR}(M_1')$.  Since $\eta$ has a cohomology class, $d\eta = 0$.  Stokes's theorem now yields

$$0 = \int_{M_1'} d\eta = \int_{S^{n-1}}\eta.$$

This means that $\eta$ restricts to a $0$-volume form on $S^{n-1}$ which, as you know, implies that it restricts to an exact form.  Thus, $i^\ast(\eta) = 0$ where $i:S^{n-1}\cong \partial M_1'\rightarrow M_1'$ denotes the inclusion and $i^\ast:H^{n-1}_{dR}(M_1')\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(\partial M_1')$ is the induced map.$\square$

Comment: Parenthetically, the $p=1$ case is a nice illustration of how one typically works with the "beginning" of a long exact sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You have the sequence $$H^{n-1}(U\cup V) \to H^{n-1}(U)\oplus H^{n-1}(V)\to H^{n-1}(U\cap V \simeq S^{n-1}) = \mathbb{R} \to H^n(U\cup V) = \mathbb{R} \ \to H^n(U)\oplus H^n(V) = 0 \to 0$$ where $U, V$ are correspondingly $\tilde{M_1}, \tilde{M_2}.$

Since $U\cup V  = M_1\sharp M_2$ is oriented and compact, by Poincare duality, $H^n(U\cup V) = \mathbb{R}$ and $H^n(U) = H^n(V) = 0.$

So we deduce that $H^{n-1}(M_1\sharp M_2) = H^{n-1}(U)\oplus H^{n-1}(V).$

Again, by Poincare duality, $H^1(M_1\sharp M_2) = H^{n-1}(M_1\sharp M_2).$

PS: maybe you know it, if we have a finite exact sequence (of finitely-dimensional vector spaces) $\ldots\to V_i\to V_{i+1} \to V_{i+2} \to \ldots$ then we have $\sum (-1)^i \dim V_i =0.$ It will help the computation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the Poincare duality theorem is in Chapter 18 where I haven't learned it yet...

Comment: No problem, just an idea which may be helpful for you. Without Poincare duality, we can somehow compute the cohomology, but with tricky computations which are maybe lengthy to post on the forum.

Comment: ah, the Poincare duality is not very difficult theorem to learn, you may pass the reading to the theorem to acquire more tools to compute de Rham cohomology. The only prerequisite is some knowledge on Five Lemma, Good Covers etc.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!